# Find two vectors and angle between them

Tags: python, algorithm, math, geometry, box2d

I have a vehicle and a dot representing pedestrian, I was able to find both vectors a and b (see picture below) and then I tried to calculate the angle between them

I use known formula that cos(Angle) = magnitude(vector_a)*magnitude(vector_a))/dot_product(vector_a,vector_b) but when I calculate the cosine it is much bigger than one so it is impossible to calculate the angle... What am I doing wrong?

```py
    def detect_pedestrian(car,pedestrian):
        #Find a vector which connects pedestrian with a car
        pedestrian_position = pedestrian.body.position
        car_position = car.body.position

        #Find vectors a and b
        car_vector = Box2D.b2Body.__GetTransform(car.body).R.GetYAxis()
        pedestrian_vector = pedestrian_position - car_position

        #Calculate magnitudes of both vector
        pedestrian_vector_magnitude = np.linalg.norm(pedestrian_vector)
        car_vector_magnitude = np.linalg.norm(car_vector)

        #Normalize both vectors
        pedestrian_vector_normalized = pedestrian_vector/pedestrian_vector_magnitude
        car_vector_normalized = car_vector/car_vector_magnitude

        #Calculate angle
        magnitudes = pedestrian_vector_magnitude * car_vector_magnitude
        dot_product = b2Dot(pedestrian_vector_normalized, car_vector_normalized)
        cosine = magnitudes/dot_product
        arccos = np.arccos(cosine)

        print(cosine)
```

[image]

Thank you very much

Comment: Did you try to solve mathematically first, maybe on paper?

Comment: Yes, I was able to solve it when I considered the vehicle stationary and its center as an origin, but the car is moving and therefore its center is moving as well... This is what I am stuck on...

Comment: But this code has nothing to do with movement. I mean, you would need a separate function to control the movement (like increment the position and call the calculation again to find new vectors and angle).

Comment: Ok, my fault, I should have mentioned that I have another function which control the movement of a car and I call both functions (this and the controlling one) in pygame main game loop, so both car and pedestrian positions are calculated in each iteration of the loop

Comment: And also I have a function in a class Pedestrian which controls movement of a pedestrian and that is also called in the main loop

Comment: So, I assume that you are doing as follows at the game loop:
1 - calculate the pedestrian position in its own function
2 - calculate the car movement in its own function
3 - try to call this function to calculate the vectors and the angle.

If that is the case I suggest you print the current position of both first thing in this function, that way we can check if the problem is with the math implementation or the other functions.

Comment: I did what you told me to do, see edit for results

Comment: Using the two examples, I suggest you use them to calculate (by hand (ok, maybe with a calculator)) the expected results and use that to create a unit test for this function. I also suggest you to print each step during the calculation to get more insights.

Comment: Please see my latest edit

Comment: I isolated the code into a simple script and passed the values directly like carx, cary, pedx, pedy and there are many strange calculations. N1 is being calculated to a negative value, I tried then to use it inside abs(), however this gives 325.971 for the angle and that is a problem for the arccos (which operates from -1 to 1. I hope that helps

Comment: Taking square roots of the individual coordinate differences is surely wrong.  As you’re probably aware, you’re not done with the paper-and-pencil part.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the difficulty is with vector algebra, not programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the car's *heading* and the position of the pedestrian relative to the car. If you have the positions of the pedestrian and the car in world coordinates (i.e. absolute position) and the velocity of the car, the code is straightforward:

```py
import numpy as np

def detect_pedestrian(car_vector, pedestrian_vector, car_velocity):
    pedestrian_relative = pedestrian_vector - car_vector
    pedestrian_length = np.linalg.norm(pedestrian_relative)
    velocity_length = np.linalg.norm(car_velocity)
    dot_product = np.dot(pedestrian_relative, car_velocity)
    cosine = dot_product / (pedestrian_length * velocity_length)
    return(np.arccos(cosine))

car = np.array([5, 2])
pedestrian = np.array([2, 3])
v = np.array([0, 2])

angle_rad = detect_pedestrian(car, pedestrian, v)
print(f"Pedestrian angle: {np.degrees(angle_rad)}°")
# Pedestrian angle: 71.56505117707799°
```

Comment: Thank you very much, seems to be working perfectly!!